# EF MVC4 returning null after updating entries in many to many relationship

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I have a many to many relationship b/w drivers and vehicle entity, at the time of driver creation, many vehicles can be assigned to a driver, it works fine, but when I want to edit and update records I am getting null collection of vehicles,

Here are my Models :

```
 public class Driver {
   public int driverId {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Vehicle> Vehicles {get;set;}
 } 
 public class Vehicle {
   public int Vehicle_Id {get;set;}
   public string Vehicle_Type_Name {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Driver> Drivers {get;set;}
 }
```

Here I define the relationship:

```
   modelBuilder
    .Entity<Driver>()
    .HasMany<Vehicle>(d => d.Vehicles)
    .WithMany(d => d.Drivers).Map(
  cs =>
   {                   
      cs.MapLeftKey("DriverId")
      .MapRightKey("VehicleId")
      .ToTable("DriversVehicles");
   });
```

And my driver View Model

```
public class DriverViewModel
{
    public DriverViewModel()
    {
        SelectedVehicles=new List<int>();
        VehicleList = new List<Vehicle>();
    }

    public Driver driver { get; set; }
    public List<int> SelectedVehicles { get; set; }
    public List<Vehicle> VehicleList { get; set; }
}
```

And here is driver Edit() Controller Action :

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        DriverViewModel DriverVm = new DriverViewModel();


        var list = db.vehicles.Select(
        v => new { v.Vehicle_Id,v.Vehicle_Type_Name }).ToList();
        DriverVm.driver = db.drivers.Find(id);

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            DriverVm.VehicleList.Add(new Vehicle { Vehicle_Id = item.Vehicle_Id, Vehicle_Type_Name = item.Vehicle_Type_Name });
        }
        foreach (var item in DriverVm.driver.Vehicles)
        {
            DriverVm.SelectedVehicles.Add(item.Vehicle_Id);
        }

        return View(DriverVm);
    }
```

And here is POST action for edit:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(DriverViewModel driverVm)
    {
        var list = db.vehicles.Select(v =>
            new { v.Vehicle_Id, v.Vehicle_Type_Name }).ToList();

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            driverVm.VehicleList.Add(
         new Vehicle { 
             Vehicle_Id = item.Vehicle_Id, 
             Vehicle_Type_Name = item.Vehicle_Type_Name 
        });
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(driverVm.driver).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            List<Vehicle> vhcls = new List<Vehicle>();

            Driver driver = db.drivers.Find(driverVm.driver.driverId);
            vhcls = driver.Vehicles.ToList();

            foreach (Vehicle veh in vhcls)
            {
                driver.Vehicles.Remove(veh);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();

            foreach (var item in driverVm.SelectedVehicles)
            {
               Vehicle vehicle = db.vehicles.Find(item);
               driverVm.driver.Vehicles.Add(vehicle);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();

            TempData["DriverSuccess"] = "1";
            return RedirectToAction("Edit");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.DriverError = "1";
        }
        return View(driverVm);
    }
```

The actual problem is here :

```
        Driver driver = db.drivers.Find(driverVm.driver.driverId);
        vhcls = driver.Vehicles.ToList();

        foreach (Vehicle veh in vhcls)
        {
            driver.Vehicles.Remove(veh);
        }
        db.SaveChanges()
```

The list "vhcls" in the above code is empty, it should contain the vehicles associated with drivers, but "driver" object contains Null collection in "driverVm.driver.Vehicles" instead of having associated vehicles, I am wandering badly but can't find the solution..Please help......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using `find` won't include related entities. It's very likely that driver contains the right entity, but that the Vehicles collection is empty.

Try using `Include` to make sure that the related entities will be included, and `FirstOrDefault` to emulate the result of `Find`.

```
Driver driver = db.drivers
    .Include(d => d.Vehicles)
    .FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == driverVm.driver.driverId);

vhcls = driver.Vehicles.ToList();
```

**Edit:** I initially missed that you were already using Lazy Loading, so I adjusted the answer a bit.

Comment: Thanks @kettch,You are great, i have been using lazyloading before but it was not working fine...Eager Loading is working fine,Thanks again......